# How to access element value from generated classes using PyXB

Tags: pyxb

As an example we have the following xml file (simplified to the point):

```
<doc>some text <deprecated> some more text <ref> even more text</ref></deprecated>
```

I am able to access the information of deprecated and ref but unfortunately I cannot seem to be able to get the value of the doc which is "some text ".

You would expect that root.doc would return you the value but it doesn't instead it returns:

```
<asdf_classes.documentation object at 0x7fb6ba3f2780>
```

However, root.doc.deprecated returns a value and root.doc.ref does as well.

Looking at the generated file from PyXB, it seems that the .doc is a class named "documentation" which contains ref and deprecated. So how can I access the value of doc if the generated class doesn't have it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

```
 print doc.value()
```

You can get the element value by adding ".value() to the element.